# What should i change to ensure that my code will display the desired output?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

So, i am having a slight issue with my code and i think it's probably due to foreach loop but if i put a break in it, it will no longer go to the other else if blocks which is an issue. Thus, i would like your help if possible.

This is my code - the loop.

```cs
foreach (Pokemon p in pokemons)
{
    if (p.Name == "pikachu" || p.Name == "Pikachu")
    {
        if (pikacount >= pikaNoToEvolve)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name + "-->" + pikaEvolveTo);
        }
    }
    else if (p.Name == "eevee" || p.Name == "Eevee")
    {
        if (eveecount >= eeveeNoToEvolve)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name + "-->" + eeveeEvolveTo);
        }                       
    }
    else if (p.Name == "charmander" || p.name == "Charmander")
    {
        if (charmcount >= charNoToEvolve)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name + "-->" + charEvolveTo);
        }
    }
}
```

The output should be something like this if the condition is fulfilled

```
Pikachu -> Raichu
Charmander -> Charmeleon
Eevee -> Flareon
```

but instead my output is as such since it loops through the list

```
Pikachu -> Raichu
Pikachu -> Raichu
Charmander -> Charmeleon
Eevee -> Flareon
Eevee -> Flareon
Eevee -> Flareon
```

My pokemons list currently contains 3 Eevee and 2 Pikachu and 1 Charmander. The condition is that if the pokemon has this many number of itself, then it will be eligible to evolve. E.g if i have two pikachu in my list, it would be eligible to evolve and be displayed. But, now since it loops through the list, it will list out Pikachu -> Raichu twice since i have 2 pikachu in my list. What should i amend to get my desired output where when the pokemon is ready to evolve, it should only display that one line instead of repeated lines.

Comment: Please don't edit (solved) into your question's title. People can see that this question has answers, which is enough.

Comment: OP: if it's solved, you should indicate that by accepting the answer that helped you the most. If you fixed it yourself, you can answer your own question (and you should potentially come back after 2 days and accept your own answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a bool type variables to keep state whether or not the pokemon has already been created. if it's the first time you'll create it, just change the value to true and it won't print it again the next time.

also, you can use `Equals1("someString", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` instead of comparing the pokemon name twice.

```
var pikachuFound = false;
var eeveeuFound = false;
var charmanderFound = false;
foreach (Pokemon p in pokemons)
{
    if (p.Name.Equals("pikachu", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        if (pikacount >= pikaNoToEvolve && !pikachuFound)
        {
            pikachuFound = true;
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name + "-->" + pikaEvolveTo);
        }
    }
    else if (p.Name.Equals("eevee", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        if (eveecount >= eeveeNoToEvolve && !eeveeuFound)
        {
            eeveeuFound = true;
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name + "-->" + eeveeEvolveTo);
        }                       
    }
    else if (p.Name.Equals("charmanderFound", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        if (charmcount >= charNoToEvolve && !charmanderFound)
        {
            charmanderFound = true
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name + "-->" + charEvolveTo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would group the Pokémon by name. This also gives you the number of Pokémon having the same name with `g.Count()`. So, you do not have to calculate these numbers separately.

```cs
var groups = pokemons
    .GroupBy(p => p.Name.ToLower());
foreach (var g in groups) {
    switch (g.Key) { // Key is the Name in lower case since we grouped by it.
        case "pikachu":
            if (g.Count() >= pikaNoToEvolve)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.Name + "-->" + pikaEvolveTo);
            }
            break;
        case "eevee":
            if (g.Count() >= eeveeNoToEvolve)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.Name + "-->" + eeveeEvolveTo);
            }
            break;
        case "charmander":
            if (g.Count() >= charNoToEvolve)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.Name + "-->" + charEvolveTo);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

But this can be improved by adding `NoToEvolve` and `EvolveTo`(and so on)  properties to the `Pokemon` class. Then you can simply write

```cs
var groups = pokemons
    .GroupBy(p => p.Name.ToLower());
foreach (var g in groups) {
    Pokemon p = g.First();
    if (g.Count() >= p.NoToEvolve)
    {
        foreach (Pokemon pEvolve in g.Take(p.NumEvolve)) {
            Console.WriteLine(pEvolve.Name + "-->" + pEvolve.EvolveTo);
            pEvolve.Name = pEvolve.EvolveTo;
        }
    }
}
```

---

If the game is only text-based, then you probably do not have data specific to an individual Pokémon. If it was a graphical game, then you at least have coordinates for each individual.

If you only have data specific to Pokémon types, then it would be easier to just have exactly one object per Pokémon type. The `Pokemon` class (now better called `PokemonType`) would have a `Count` property, telling how many Pokémon of this type exist.

This would make the handling easier. No need to count, no need to group, no need to convert Pokémon, etc. Only change the `Count` in the old and new Pokémon types when a Pokémon evolves.

Comment: Something to consider, which is not made clear is if there are a number of Pokémon eligible to evolve. For example, if the list includes 4 Pikachus, then technically 2 can evolve to a Raichu. If the intension is that now that `Pikachu -> Raichu` should be listed twice, this answer will not produce the desired output. Instead, it will always list the Pokémon type that is eligible for evolution only once, even if multiple of that type are eligible for an evolution.

Comment: The group `g` is an `IEnumerable<Pokemon>`. So you can get the required number of them with e.g. `g.Take(2)` and loop over it with foreach. Put these numbers and the logic governing these aspects into the class, so that you can get rid of the `switch` or the `if else if else if...`.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes, thank you for giving an alternative solution and explanation. I didn't think of using switch case instead of if else. I learned something new thanks to you. Once again, thank you and have a nice day :)